# Xcode IOS 8.3 swift how to check if bluetooth is connected?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Does anyone know a way to just check if Bluetooth is connected for iOS?
I'm just looking to check for connection, and not trying to connect.

Answer (score 3):

You would probably use [`CBCentralManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:) for that. You can use `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices` to get a list of things that are connected based on their service UUID. If all you want to know is if Bluetooth is on or off, examine the `state` property of a CBCentralManager instance to determine if it is powered on or off.

Comment: I ended up just doing CBCentralManager and CBPeripheralManager to show connection with the Bluetooth device. Thank you for the help. Only problem now is that when I connect to Bluetooth (in the program) it works intermittently.

Comment: CBCentralManager and CBPeripheralManager can not open bluetooth iphone 5s ios 8.3 , help me

Comment: retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices is deprecated now. Please don't use it.